# Remove Cookies From Wordpress Core

Tags: theme-development, cookies

I'm developing a custom theme and i understand Wordpress does come with some built-in cookies?  With the new GDPR regulations coming I would like to remove these - I believe they are only there log-in / username purposes.  The site is for my own company and it's just a brochure site with no data being gathered at all. I don't mind having to type my details in whenever I login.

How do i remove Wordpress cookies from Wordpress itself?

Many thanks,

Comment: I just did some tests on this, and just browsing around a wordpress doesnt set any cookies if you dont try to login in anyway, comments/admin. so long as you dont have any other plugins making them. inspect them with the web developer toolbar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to log in to WordPress *at all* without cookies. It's not just about remembering if you're logged in the next day, it's about remembering if you're logged in *every time you go to a different page in the admin*.

[image: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser message]

The only [cookies WordPress adds *itself*](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies) (so not counting plugins) are for logging in and for commenting. You only need the login ones to be able to use the admin, and the comment ones are only relevant if you have comments enabled.

So if your regular users aren't doing either of those things then you and your site are not using cookies to identify users and have nothing you need to gain consent for.

The situation is obviously different if you're using analytics, ads, plugins, or anything else that uses cookies, but then that doesn't have anything to do with WordPress itself.

Comment: Oh OK I didn't realise that. So if a visitor only visits the site (i.e. never has to log-in) then they never get served a WP cookie?  The site isn't going to have an 3rd party cookies at all.

Comment: I can't find any documentation of, or code for, any cookies WordPress might set without the user logging in or commenting.

Comment: Note that in the next version of WP, there's a checkbox added to the comment form as a part of the GDPR compliance group, so no cookie changes will be necessary